# How to break a line in window form application?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text += textBox1.Text + "\n\n";
    textBox1.Text = "";
}
```

I have tried  using `\n` and `\br` but i could not get it.

Comment: What about Enviroment.NewLine ?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Environment.NewLine Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

The property value of NewLine is a constant customized specifically for the current platform and implementation of the .NET Framework. this property containing `"\r\n"` for *non-Unix platforms*, or  `"\n"` for *Unix platforms*.

Comment: @MaruthiRam Accept the answer if its fills your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

```
string text2 = "line1\r\nline2";
```

But it is better to use [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.environment.newline.aspx).

```
string text = "line1" + Environment.NewLine + "line2";
```